# ECC Public key import understanding

Tags: elliptic-curves, openssl

I am working out ICAO verification process (biometric IDs), and here is one of their publicly available certificates:

```
# openssl x509 -in 492F0116.crt -text -noout
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number: 1227817238 (0x492f0116)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Issuer: C = GB, O = UKKPA, CN = Country Signing Authority
    Validity
        Not Before: Feb  1 00:00:00 2022 GMT
        Not After : Jun  1 00:00:00 2033 GMT
    Subject: C = GB, O = HM Passport Office, OU = London, CN = Document Signing Key 37
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub:
                04:1a:35:73:02:b5:21:4a:7d:b7:00:03:55:53:f8:
                c3:7a:d4:f1:93:ca:b0:d8:4b:a6:4b:68:e4:ce:fa:
                71:f7:08:4b:9e:e8:47:33:b9:f4:b6:03:b1:2d:94:
                e9:47:bf:60:f9:2d:3b:19:47:7f:7d:e1:2d:e7:55:
                00:fd:e2:2c:b2
            Field Type: prime-field
            Prime:
                00:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:
                00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                ff:ff:ff
            A:
                00:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:00:00:01:00:00:00:00:00:00:
                00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                ff:ff:fc
            B:
                5a:c6:35:d8:aa:3a:93:e7:b3:eb:bd:55:76:98:86:
                bc:65:1d:06:b0:cc:53:b0:f6:3b:ce:3c:3e:27:d2:
                60:4b
            Generator (uncompressed):
                04:6b:17:d1:f2:e1:2c:42:47:f8:bc:e6:e5:63:a4:
                40:f2:77:03:7d:81:2d:eb:33:a0:f4:a1:39:45:d8:
                98:c2:96:4f:e3:42:e2:fe:1a:7f:9b:8e:e7:eb:4a:
                7c:0f:9e:16:2b:ce:33:57:6b:31:5e:ce:cb:b6:40:
                68:37:bf:51:f5
            Order:
                00:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
                ff:ff:bc:e6:fa:ad:a7:17:9e:84:f3:b9:ca:c2:fc:
                63:25:51
            Cofactor:  1 (0x1)
            Seed:
                c4:9d:36:08:86:e7:04:93:6a:66:78:e1:13:9d:26:
                b7:81:9f:7e:90
    X509v3 extensions: ...
```

I tried to import this certificate to [python ECC](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/ecc.html) and I am always getting:

```
File "C:\Users\snowx\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\ECC.py", line 1757, 
in import_key
raise ValueError("Invalid DER encoding inside the PEM file")

ValueError: Invalid DER encoding inside the PEM file
```

So, that is the first question. But more importantly, could someone point me out what all those A/B parameters are i.e. what curve is used here?

Original cert:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIESTCCA9CgAwIBAgIESS8BFjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBBMQswCQY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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I think I see the math behind it: https://loup-vaillant.fr/tutorials/cofactor but in practical terms - what library can handle it?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. That said, you've got a *certificate*, not just a public key, so importing a public key won't work. You have to import the certificate to Python and extract the key (or extract the key and import that).

Answer (score 2):

The curve used [looks to be](https://neuromancer.sk/std/nist/P-256) NIST P-256 AKA SECG SECP256r1 AKA x.962 prime256v1 (it's got lots of names because lots of organizations standardized it).

The programming portion of the question is off-topic for this site, particularly as you didn't state which library you're using so we can't even look up the documentation for it. However, there's almost certainly a way to import an x.509 Certificate (what you have) and to get the public key from that imported object. If not, the commonly-used [pyca/cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/index.html) library can do so.